# Wierd Error When Adding New Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a problem when saving a new entity into the database. Whenever I save the new entity `DbEntityValidationException` occurs. But carefully looking at the values of the variable and the data annotations of my entity, I meet all of them.

I looked at the database and problem seems to be not on the entity I am adding, but on the previous entities saved in the database. For some reason, some of the foreign key fields which previously have values before the adding of entity are now NULL!

During debugging, I scanned all of these entities and before I call `SaveChanges()` method, those fields are there and not null. Then after calling `SaveChanges()`, the validation error occurs because I think `SaveChanges()` might have done something that made the other records mess up.

I don't know if this has something to do with it but when I create a new entity, I create a new instance of it and assign its property individually. Some of it's property came from entity framework and are attached. So I am assigning an attached property to a detached new object. I don't know if this caused the weird behavior. Here is an example excerpt:

```
Book book = new Book();
book.Title = "The FooBar";
book.Publisher = publisherRepository.Get(1); // will retrieve a Publisher object from EF

bookRepository.Add(book);

....

// under BookRepository class
public void Add(Book book)
{
   dbContext.Books.Add(book);
   // just to check if the other records are not messed up, I did this and
   // check the values in VS Debugger
   // At this point, the other records are not yet affected.
   var books = dbContext.Books.Include("Publisher").ToArray();

   dbContext.SaveChanges(); // error thrown here, 
   // checking at the validation error, other book 
   //instances have their Publisher property set to NULL!
}
```

Please help as I can't find other solution to this problem. I am an Entity Framework newbie myself.

Comment: What is the actual validation error you get? What happens in `publisherRepository.Get(1)`?

Comment: It's saying the Publisher property is null, but looking at the entity I am adding, there is value for it. The Publisher property is required. The problem is when I call `SaveChanges()`, the OTHER previously valid entities have their Publisher property NULL. I don't know what caused it since I am not updating them prior to adding of the new entity.

Comment: `publisherRepository.Get(1)` simply retrieves a `Publisher` instance from db with the id of 1.

Answer (score 1):

In this line `var books = dbContext.Books.Include("Publisher")` you are running a query on the database and telling entity framework to include all the Publishers linked to all the Books. But there are no Publishers in the database linked to books yet. So all the Books in context have Publishers set back to null.

That line has interfered with your debugging and is now adding to the confusion.

If you remove that line and go back to the original error I think you will find that the issue is to do with an attempt to add a Publisher that already exists. That happens when you do this:

```
book.Publisher = publisherRepository.Get(1);
bookRepository.Add(book);
```

The `Add` method marks the entire graph (i.e. both the `Book` and the `Publisher`) as `Added`, but the Publisher already exists in the database so that is incorrect.

You can avoid the problem by using a foreign key on the Book. Like this:

```
book.PublisherID = 1;
bookRepository.Add(book);
```

There is a comprehensive explanation of this behavior here:

[Why does entity framework reinsert existing objects into my database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx)

Comment: I am actually reading the very article in the link before you posted this. Thanks, I might take a look at using foreign keys first and update if it somehow fixed the error.

Comment: Could you explain more this statement: "But there are no Publishers in the database linked to books yet. So all the Books in context have Publishers set back to null.". There are already some books pointing to the same Publisher that is used by the new entity.

Comment: Are you sure they are in the database? Not just set in the context and not saved yet?

Comment: Yes I am, I save a list of books and a list of publishers on the `Seed()` method of the database initializer. I also called `SaveChanges()` in the `Seed()` method.

Comment: But do you link Publishers to Books in the Seed method? Have the foreign keys have been set in the database?

Comment: I link the `Publisher` instance into the previously added `Books`. I did all of the linking and called `SaveChanges()` at the end. The foreign keys are properly set in the database. The problem occurs when adding a new entity. Those previously set foreign keys became NULL (only on some entities).

Comment: Beats me then...sorry. Only on some? Must be some clue there?

Comment: Well the error doesn't happen if I start without seeding Books and creating them one by one.

Comment: Anyway, I will try using foreign keys. I think that is the problem to this. If it works, then I will mark this as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, removing the [Required] attributes on navigation properties somehow removed the errors. I still fully don't get why the other rows are affected.